# Entity Framework, how to avoid this issue?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a method like this:

```
    public FbUser FindUserByGraphOrInsert(dynamic json, bool commit = false)
    {
        string graphId = json.id;

        EntityDataModelContext context = DataContext.GetDataContext();
        FbUser user = context.FbUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.FbGraphId == graphId);

        if (user == null)
        {
            user = new FbUser();
            user.FbGraphId = json.id;
            user.FbUsername = StringExtensions.UnicodeDecode(json.name);

            context.FbUsers.AddObject(user);

            if (commit)
                context.SaveChanges();
        }

        return user;
    }
```

I call this method repeatedly in a loop (say upwards of 80 times), with `commit = false`

Thing is, I expected this method to let me know if the user is already in the context, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

The result is that when I finally save changes, I get a list of 80 users, where 27 are distinct.

I expect this method to return those 27, how could I change it to achieve this?
Do I really need to save changes every single time?

Comment: Have you tried using the distict() at the end of your context selection

Comment: before saving it you might actually added to a list and then get all the distinct elements from the list using the .Distinct() it would only get distinct elements from the list and using for each element that distinct to save  this way you only adding distinct elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Polity's answer, I implemented the following extension method, which worked.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> IncludeUnsaved<T>(this ObjectSet<T> set) where T : class
    {
        var addedObjects = set.Context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added);
        var equalObjects = addedObjects.Select(e => e.Entity).OfType<T>();

        return equalObjects.Concat(set);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant 'simply' do that, the problem is that each query will always hit the database by default since EF has no way of knowing you either query the same data or that there have been no underlying changes in the database since you opened the connection.

You can however check the ChangeTracker/ObjectStateManager for existing changed objects and query that one as well prior to deciding to add a new object.

Sample:

```
var addedObjects = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added);
var equalObjects = addedObjects.OfType<MyEntity>().Where(x => x.Name == newObject.Name);
```

Comment: In order to do this though you would need to use a single context and pass it around, instead of instantiating every time.  A lower impact way to see what ID's you've already added though would be to just maintain a `List<string>` outside of this method and see if it contains the ID before adding or something.

Comment: I do use a single context. That's what `DataContext.GetDataContext()` does.

Comment: @Nico - be aware that having a single data context shared can bring up some problems. EF is simply not made to be shared, it is ment to be opened, used for something particular and closed. For sharing data, you can use layer in between like a repository and for automicy you can fall back to transactions

Comment: @Polity the context lives through a request, during the lifetime of a console application or through a wcf svc request, depending on where it's called from. In this case, I'll be executing this on a service, I guess.

Comment: @Polity slight fix: `addedObjects.Select(e => e.Entity).OfType<T>();`, but thanks a lot!